# Centering a div horizontally inside a container which can change dimensions

Tags: html, css, alignment

I need to center a `div ('#expand')` in a container. The `div` may overlap the content in the container, but only the visible part (i.e. no margins left or right from the `div` overlapping the content) [This example](http://jsbin.com/utaxak/4/edit) seems to work (using another container and margins on auto), but I need it to overlap the border of the container.

Comment: I don't think anybody actually understands what you're trying to accomplish but I could be wrong.

Comment: Can you show some of your code and what you tried?

Comment: There is a link to a jsbin I created as an example. The example works for almost everything, but I need the 'Expand' button to overlap the border of the container. I don't know wheter that can be achieved without rewriting the whole thing.

Answer (score 1):

I'm unsure about what you're looking for, exactly, but if you're looking to center an element, you would typically do this:

```
div#expand{margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;}
```